# some ?> appears in my page all tags opned are closed

Tags: php, html, tags

I met some trouvle in my pages, some ?> ?> ?> ?> ?> ?> ?> does appears in my page, it seems lie the code is not interpreted, but all is closed and I do not know where it can comes from

below is my code

```
<?php
//For weight change
$down_icon = 'images/thumb_down.gif';
$same_icon = 'images/cool.gif';
$up_icon = 'images/thumb_up.gif';
$comment_icon = 'images/notebook.gif';

//DB Values for icons
$status_icons[0] = $down_icon;
$status_icons[1] = $same_icon;
$status_icons[2] = $up_icon;
?>
<style>
    .fif {display: inline-block; 
      padding-left:5px;
      padding-right: 5px; 
/*    box-shadow: 8px 8px 0px #aaa;
          border-width:1px;
            border-style:dashed;
            border-color:black;}*/
    }
</style>
<table class="noborder">
    <tr><td>
            <div class="uibutton-group">
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=1">Lundi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=2">Mardi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=3">Mercredi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=4">Jeudi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=5">Vendredi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=6">Samedi</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=7">Dimanche</a>
            </div>  
        </td>
        <td><b>Derniers jours en arrière </b> </td>
        <td><div class="uibutton-group">
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=<?php echo $_GET['day'] ?>&farback=30">30</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=<?php echo $_GET['day'] ?>&farback=60">60</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=<?php echo $_GET['day'] ?>&farback=90">90</a>
                <a class="uibutton" href="index.php?p=history&day=<?php echo $_GET['day'] ?>&farback=120">120</a>
            </div></td>
    </tr>
</table><p><br></p>
<div class="maindivforexos" style="width:100%;display:inline-block">
    <?php
    if (!isset($_GET['day'])) {
    $_GET['day'] = 1;
    }
    if (isset($_GET['farback'])) {
    $farback = $_GET['farback'];
    } else {
    $farback = 28;
    }
    $query = "SELECT `record` FROM `workouts` 
          WHERE `workouts`.`day_number`='1' 
          AND `workouts`.`user` = {$_SESSION['userid']} 
          AND  `workouts`.`record` >= SUBDATE(now(),INTERVAL {$farback} day) 
          GROUP BY `record` ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!mysql_num_rows($result)):
    ?>
        <div class=warning>Il n'y a pas d'enregistrements pour ce jour.</div>
    <?php
    else:
    while ($cr = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        ?>
        <div style="width:200px"  class="fif"><table style="width:100%">
            <tr class="fbgreybox">
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">
                <img src="images/calendar_2.png"> Séance du : <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($cr['record'])) ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT `exercise` FROM `workouts` WHERE `record` = '{$cr['record']}' AND `user`= {$_SESSION['userid']} GROUP BY `exercise`";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($exo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :
            ?>
                <tr class="fbinfobox">
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left">
                    <img src="images/Sport-dumbbell.png"> <?php echo exerciseName($exo['exercise']) ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Séries</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Reps</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Poids</td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            $rqt = "SELECT `set_number`, `reps`, `weight` FROM `workouts` WHERE `exercise` = {$exo['exercise']} AND `record` = '{$cr['record']}' AND `user` = {$_SESSION['userid']} ORDER BY `set_number`";
            $result2 = mysql_query($rqt);
            while ($detail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)):
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    Série <?php echo $detail['set_number'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $detail['reps'] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $detail['weight'] ?>
                </td>
                </tr>
                ?>

                <?php
            endwhile;
            endwhile;
            ?>
        </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

[image]

I really have no Idead on where it can comes from because All tags opened are closed.
It appears between the div and the table in the loop

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: you have one '?>' in while loop.
See:

<td>
 <?php echo $detail['weight'] ?>
</td>
</tr>
?>

Remove this extra '?>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is an extra closing PHP tag in your code.

```
<?php echo $detail['weight'] ?>
</td>
</tr>
?> <----------here
```

Comment: oh thank you so much I did not seen that since I'm refactoring that code, I was searching for that since yesterday and in few seconds you find it, thank you so much

Comment: Recurring "anomalies" are usually found inside loops. Glad I could assist. :)